# Using docker-compose to create tables in postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to deploy a multicontainer python Flask web application. I'm having difficulty understanding how to create tables in the postgresql database during the build so I don't have to add them manually with psql.

My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/flask-app/static
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 app:app

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

data:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: "true"

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

I dont want to have to enter psql in order to type in:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database;
CREATE USER this_user WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "my_database" to this_user;
\i create_tables.sql
```

I would appreciate guidance on how to create the tables.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> I dont want to have to enter psql in order to type in

You can simply use container's built-in init mechanism:

`COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-init.sql`

This makes sure that your sql is executed after DB server is properly booted up.

Take a look at their entrypoint [script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh). It does some preparations to start psql correctly and looks into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory for files ending in `.sh`, `.sql` and `.sql.gz`.

`10-` in filename is because files are processed in ASCII order. You can name your other init files like `20-create-tables.sql` and `30-seed-tables.sql.gz` for example and be sure that they are processed in order you need.

Also note that invoking command [does not](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L116) specify the database. Keep that in mind if you are, say, migrating to docker-compose and your existing `.sql` files don't specify DB either.

Your files will be processed at container's first start instead of `build` stage though. Since Docker Compose stops images and then resumes them, there's almost no difference, but if it's crucial for you to init the DB at `build` stage I suggest still using built-in init method by calling `/docker-entrypoint.sh` from your dockerfile and then cleaning up at `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory.

Comment: this doesnt work with the latest version of the postgres image :(

Answer (score 72):

It didn't work for me with the `COPY` approach in `Dockerfile`. But I managed to run my `init.sql` file by adding the following to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

`init.sql` was in the same directory as my `docker-compose.yml`.
I picked the solution from [this](https://gist.github.com/vrulevskyi/307b08abddc9568cf8f9c1b429c1ab56) gist. Check [this](https://onexlab-io.medium.com/docker-compose-postgres-initdb-ba0021deef76) article for more information.

Answer (score 13):

I would create the tables as part of the build process.  Create a new `Dockerfile` in a new directory `./database/`

```
FROM postgres:latest
COPY . /fixtures
WORKDIR /fixtures
RUN /fixtures/setup.sh
```

`./database/setup.sh` would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

/etc/init.d/postgresql start
psql -f create_fixtures.sql    
/etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

Put your create user, create database, create table sql (and any other fixture data) into a `create_fixtures.sql` file in the `./database/` directory.

and finally your `postgres` service will change to use `build`:

```
postgres:
    build: ./database/
    ...
```

Note: Sometimes you'll need a `sleep 5` (or even better a script to poll and wait for postgresql to start) after the `/etc/init.d/postgresql start` line.  In my experience either the init script or the psql client handles this for you, but I know that's not the case with mysql, so I thought I'd call it out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've run into this error when building the docker-compose.yml. `bin/sh: 1: /fixtures/setup.sh: Permission denied
Service 'postgres' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /fixtures/setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 126`

Comment: Ok, you can add `set -x` to the top of the script as well, so it will print out each step, and you can figure out where it's failing.

Comment: I added `RUN chmod +x /fixtures/setup.sh` which resolved that problem. I now get `No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster" ... (warning).
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Service 'postgres' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /fixtures/setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 2`

Comment: Ok, I think you're hitting the case I describe in the "Note" at the bottom of the answer

Comment: Did you ever get around this cluster issue?

Comment: This sounds a lot like provisioning. Wouldn't it be better to use ad-hoc tools for that, e.g. Ansible?

Comment: Do you mean to `COPY` and `WORKDIR` the `database` directory? What is the `fixtures/` directory for?

Comment: No, it's not the database directory. `fixtures` is a directory which contains `.sql` files which can be loaded into the database.